# How can I process incoming MMS messages

Tags: android, mms

I want our app to examine incoming SMS and MMS messages, examine their contents, then if they are something we are interested in, log and display them.  Then block them from going to the standard messaging app.  We've had this working with SMS messages for a while, but I can't find any samples or documentation explaining how to retrieve data content from incoming MMS messages.

All I've found are apps that retrieve MMS contents from the Messaging content provider.  I suppose we wait till it gets there then retrieve the content and remove it.  But that seems kind of backward.

Answer (score 1):

Check this project

http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/

It contain MMS parser implementation. But it support only header, so you can get information about type of MMS, sender phone number, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Clone this GIT repository:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base

And look to this folder core\java\com\google\android\mms\pdu\

Here is MMS header and body parser. If you can see example how to use it download also this GIT repository:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms